# How do I deal with committing to multiple branches during development?

Tags: git, version-control, mercurial, dvcs, monorepo

I'm looking for uptodate knowledge/best practice/advice.

We are considering moving to a mono-repo for our development. We use Scrum with Stories/Epics/Sprints (I'm not fully uptodate on all the terminology ... I'm old and some of the new stuff seems JUST like the old stuff ... just with different names).

We understand the need to define small units of work for a developer, but it is often the case that several units have a degree of codependence, but are for different parts of the system.

The developer may work on several simultaneously simply as that is more efficient (and makes the task easier to achieve), but the tasks are separate and each need their own review.

What we would like is to be able to have a 'checkout' of the current feature branch of code (I'm using git terminology, simply as that is what we are currently using), allow the developer to do their coding, run the tests locally, and if happy, commit specific changes to the different branches. So, for example, the migration changes go to the migration task's branch, the API modelling/mapping changes go to the appropriate task's branch, etc.

Each task is set up with the appropriate blocking for the story, so the release manager can release everything in the right order (i.e. you can't release the UI changes for a non existent column in the datastore).

To achieve anything like this with git is cumbersome in the extreme.

For us a feature branch is for a story (i.e. The client wants to be able to allow their customers the ability to change the booked session time, assuming availability exist, issuing a refund or requesting further payment if required). To achieve this story, there are various tasks that need to be done (new data, UI/UX work, API work, etc.). Each of these are defined tasks for the story. Each with their own branch which.

Are there better options?

If not, are there better practises available that anyone can recommend?

Comment: What I would do in that case is create a single branch to do "the whole thing" and separate revisions for the different separate target branches. Then, when I'm done, I would create the separate target branches and cherry-pick the changes from the "unified" branch that relate to this specific target branch.

Comment: I would have one set of development branches which includes master which is updated with the single dev branches when appropriate. The release branches, separate for each customer would get merges from master. And possibly their own dev branch (which in turn could get updates from master or other dev branches, if needed), if they require customer-specific changes.

Answer (score 0):

You may be looking for either **gitflow** (for git) or **hgflow** for Mercurial.

These are branching workflows which seem intended to solve the organization problem that you have posed.

---

**gitflow:**

Created / advocated [by Vincent Driessen](https://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/). Although this model was created with git in mind, for the most part it is not really git-specific.

> The central repo holds two main branches with an infinite lifetime:
>
> master develop
>
> We consider master to be the main branch where the source code of HEAD
>   always reflects a production-ready state.
>
> We consider develop to be the main branch which reflects a state with
>   the latest delivered development changes. Some would call this the
>   “integration branch”.
>
> When the source code in the develop branch reaches a stable point and
>   is ready to be released, all of the changes should be merged back into
>   master and then tagged with a release number.
>
> Next to the main branches we use supporting branches to aid parallel
>   development between team members, ease tracking of features, prepare
>   for production releases and to assist in quickly fixing live
>   production problems.
>
> The different types of branches we may use are:
>
> Feature branches Release branches Hotfix branches
>
> Each of these branches have a specific purpose and are bound to strict
>   rules...

([Text source](https://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/))

---

**hgflow:**

This is the Mercurial equivalent of gitflow.

> hgflow is an open-source [extension](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/FlowExtension) for Hg inspired by git-flow
>   and built around Vincent Driessen’s popular branching model. In
>   essence it formalizes the workflow around Driessen’s model and
>   provides commands for branching and merging features, releases, and
>   hotfixes within that model.
>
> ...
>
> Hgflow shouldn’t introduce any radical change to the standard source
>   control workflow, it simply introduces a more formal vocabulary for
>   describing branches and applies a nice model to the process. On top of
>   that it adds a nice bit of automation and makes working with Hg even
>   more enjoyable.

[hgflow home page](https://bitbucket.org/yujiewu/hgflow/wiki/Home.wiki#!introduction).

([text source](https://andy.mehalick.com/2011/12/24/an-introduction-to-hgflow/))

---

Also, if you haven't yet looked into how a site like **[github](http://github.com)** allows you to manage features with things like pull requests, that might be useful to think consider. As I understand it, github provides essentially tools to help enact / manage workflows such as a Driesen branching model.